# How to undo revokation of add-on permissions in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, permissions, browser-addons, firefox-extensions

I just revoked the permission to store data locally os Greasemonkey 4.3 in Firefox 59.0.2 on Ubuntu 17.10 assuming that the Firefox developers were providing an intuitive way to undoing this change. They do not! After de- and reinstalling the add-on, the permission overview which pops up after clickingo n the circuled i in the address bar still shows that the all permissions are revoked.

Comment: You can delete your firefox user profile to reset it as a last resort. You can go to Help -> Restart with Addons Disabled. On restarting it will give you a refresh option.

Comment: @GaneshR. Why think things through and provide intuitive and smart solutions... Thanks for your help. I'd accept that as an answer.